# Socket.io emitting to all users despite .to(room)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a node.js server that's using Socket.io to emit events to clients. When a connection event occurs, the new socket is placed in a room based on the connecting user's id, which is obtained using the session id cookie from `socket.headers.handshake.cookie`. I know this part is working, because I can set a breakpoint and inspect `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` and see this room:

[image]

So, the room apparently has only one socket in it. Also while paused at this breakpoint, the following expression: `userID.toString()` evaluates to: `"5cd6201acb0d5f23e465cb84"`. So, this expression should be usable to obtain the room with that one socket in it. Then, directly after the breakpoint, this code executes:

```
io.of('/').in(userID.toString()).emit('notification', notifHTML);
```

So, I would expect the notification event to only be emitted to the one socket in that room identified by that expression. The notification event is handled by the client thusly:

```
socket.on('notification', function(notifHTML){
    $("#notificationsContainer").prepend(notifHTML);
    $(".notifications-count").html('<i class="fas fa-dot-circle"></i>');
    document.title = '(⚐) sweet';
});
```

However, as it turns out, every client connected to the server recieves that notification event and handles it in the above-shown way; when I have three browsers connected to the server, all three of them execute the above code; I can see the results on the page and in the new document title.

I actually can fix this by replacing that line that has .to with the following:

```
io.of('/').in(userID.toString()).clients(async (error, clients) => {
     for (var client of clients) {
          io.sockets.connected[client].emit('notification', notifHTML);
     }
})
```

Then, the event is only emitted to the client I want it to be, the one in the room that I showed. (This room could contain multiple clients if one user connects to the server from multiple browsers, so I can't replace this room code with code to target a single socket.) However, the code shouldn't need to be this verbose; I would still like to know why .to is not working the way I expect it to. As far as I can tell from reading the docs, it should provide that same functionality of only emitting events to the sockets in a specified room.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `emit` events to all the `sockets` in a particular room, try doing...

```
io.sockets.in('my-room').emit('my-event', someData);
```

...this will `broadcast` the `event` to all `sockets` in that room in the default namespace. You can use `of('my-namespace')` with `io` to specify the namespace as well. You are missing the `sockets` part after `io` in your code.

Alternatively, doing...

```
socket.broadcast.to('my-room').emit('my-event', someData);
```

...will `broadcast` the `event` to all the `sockets` in that room except the one broadcasting.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.to` instead of `.in`

```
io.of('/').to(userID.toString()).emit('notification', notifHTML);
```